# Unity WaitFortimeSeconds internal logic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have some question.
i'm made some update 'class' for doing some event later some seconds.
someone recommand coroutine method.
i want to know how 'coroutine' waits for a certain amount of time.

why coroutine don't check some times with waitforseconds method?

what i know, coroutine was not thread. In unity lifecycle, couroutine checked with other fuctions.

if i make some code like coroutine and check times in update method. it's make many cpu troubles.

why i should use coroutine method. and how coroutine check wait times?

Comment: `why coroutine don't check some times with waitforseconds method?` please rephrase this question. I haven't seen a WaitForSeconds method in unity. Do you mean WaitForSecond class? in that case coroutine pretty much does use that class, in fact that's how you delay an operation in a coroutine.

Comment: And to what extend do you wish to know how coroutine works? Have you read the documentations and not understand something? Do you want to compare the performance to your update class? in that case please share your code and ask a specific question about what you wish to compare.

Comment: I want to know internal logic i mean how check time for wake up coroutine.

Comment: It uses unity's internal logic of-course. There's no need to dive into that since we don't have any control over it. All we need to know is coroutine uses unity's frame-based interval system and it's more efficient than using C# threads. If you want to know more you can read this article: http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post83_coroutines-more-than-you-want-to-know

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is orbetter **was** a custom JavaScript flavour-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Are you sure that is the language you are using? Also just because you are using a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't automatically mean your question is about that IDE in specific ... wat you should do though is use the tag `unity3d` as that is the main framework/API you are asking about ... and finally: Please add your code otherwise we can't help you!

Comment: @Bizhan OP is referring to [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) ;) still pretty unclear what exactly the question is though

Comment: And you won't find how it is done exactly internally since it is happening somewhere in the native backend of the engine we don't have access to. All we can see is the [c# Source Code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/WaitForSeconds.cs) level where you will only find that it inherits from `YieldInstruction` a class that does nothing itself since it is used by the native backend ... so how it works exactly you won't find here ... but rather tell us what is **your** exact use case? What are **you** trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about this. it's my first time to use stackoverflow question.  And i'm weak about english...

Comment: I just want to know about coroutine inside logic

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments the exact implementation and how it works internally is obfuscated in the underlying native C++ engine part of Unity.

The [c# Source Code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/WaitForSeconds.cs) layer doesn't tell us anything further.

As I understand your question though it is a bit more in general how [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) work at all.

As you probably already have noted all Coroutines in Unity basically something returning [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) and the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword.

Additionally per default Cooutines get their next call in `Update` every frame.

So what happens is basically is

- StartCoroutine registers an `IEnumerator` as running Coroutine
- Every frame (`Update`) it is calling [`IEnuemrator.MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) on it
- This causes the Coroutine to execute everything until it reaches a `yield` statement

Some of the special instructions like `WaitForFixedUpdate` etc work a bit different of course.

Now of course in the backend it might work slightly different but basically using

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
```

equals using e.g.

```
// This form of loop basically means you iterate it for 5 seconds
for(var timer = 0f; timer < 5; timer += Time.deltaTime)
{
    // This tells Unity to "pause" the routine here, render the current frame
    // and continue from here with the next "MoveNext" call in the next frame's Update routine
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much i want to know about this. :)

Comment: @오승학 If a answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. If it helps you give it a upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)